# FLTK output showing the latest input

Tags: c++, fltk

main.cpp

```
void torsoOPCB(Fl_Widget *w, void* p) {
    for(std::size_t i=0; i < torso.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Name: " << torso[i].GetName() << endl;
        cout << "Part Number: " << torso[i].GetPartNumber() << endl << endl;
    } // This loop is to check if the inputs are in the vector torso


    dialog = new Fl_Window(340, 300, "Robot Part");

    Fl_Multiline_Output* output = new Fl_Multiline_Output(100, 10, 400, 200, "Torso list:");


    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < torso.size(); i++) {
        output->value(torso[i].print().c_str());
    }

    dialog->end();
    dialog->set_non_modal();
    dialog->show();
}
```

I'm learning how to use FLTK in C++ and I'm not sure why it keeps showing me the latest user's inputs. For example, if I entered the inputs for torso[0] and torso[1], the output will only show torso[1] which is the latest input. The inputs are stored correctly I think but I'm not sure why it won't show both torso[0] and torso[1].

Here is my print fucntion

Torso.cpp

```
std::string Torso::print()
{
    ostringstream of;

    of << "Part name: " << GetName() 
    << endl << "Part #: " << GetPartNumber() 
    << endl << "Weight: " << GetWeight() 
    << endl << "Cost: " << GetCost()
    << endl << "Battery Comp: " << GetDescription()
    << endl << "Description: " << GetBatteryCompartmentSize() << endl;

    return of.str();
}
```

I'm using FLTK version 1.3.4. Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You are only showing the very last item in

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < torso.size(); i++) {
    output->value(torso[i].print().c_str());
}
```

The output value is always being overwritten.  If you wish to show all the output, gather it up first before putting it into the widget

```
std::ostringstream oss;
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < torso.size(); i++) {
    oss << torso[i].print() << "\n";
}
output->value(oss.str().c_str());
```

If you don't mind multiple outputs on the same line, change the "\n to ".  "